# Image size differs if captured from camera and chosen from gallery

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am facing this weird issue that if I upload an image directly from camera it's size is less (0.9 MB in my case) and if I click an image independently and then pick it from     gallery it has different size (17 MB in same case)

Is it possible Or I am missing something

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",MyURL];

UIImage *yourImage= (UIImage *)[data objectAtIndex:0]; // image picked from      gallery/camera

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
NSDictionary *userValues = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userValues"];

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSString *abc=[userValues objectForKey:@"abc"];
NSString *memberLogin=[userValues valueForKey:@"memberlogin"];

[parameters setValue:@"abcd" forKey:@"param1"];
[parameters setValue:@"1234" forKey:@"param2"];

NSMutableData *tempData = [NSMutableData data];
NSString *boundary = @"------VohpleBoundary4QuqLuK1cE5pMoCw";
NSString *FileParamConstant = @"album_image";

for (NSString *param in parameters)
{
    [tempData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [tempData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [tempData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [parameters valueForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[tempData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[tempData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[tempData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[tempData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[tempData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[tempData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
self.requestContentType = contentType;

[request setValue:requestContentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:requestContentLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:tempData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

- I Obeserved that if I use UIImageJPEGRepresentation without compression (1.0) instead of UIImageJPEGRepresentation it reduces size

Comment: It probably has a notable amount to do with file format, I'm pretty sure cameras capture in a RAW format, whereas if you were to put this onto a PC then select, it won't be in that format anymore.

That's my basic media knowledge at it's best though, I could be wrong.

Comment: if I use UIImageJPEGRepresentation it change image orientation. any solution?

Comment: Are you sure you mean orientation?

Comment: @Jack: using UIImagePNGRepresentation there is no orientation issue but it icreases image data size. and using UIImageJPEGRepresentation image gets uploaded with landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

Weird but It is resolved after using allowsEditing property of UIImagePickerController to true (using UIImagePNGRepresentation only)